# How add new group after existing group

Tags: odoo, odoo-10, odoo-9

How with xpath add new group after existing group in hr_employee.

After Birth I need add my new group

```
<group string="Birth">
    <field name="birthday"/>
</group>
```

I'm try with below example but not working

```
<xpath expr="//group[@string='Birth']" position="after">
    <group string="New group">
        <group>
            <field name="new1" />
        </group>
    </group>
</xpath>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Xpath doesnt work well with string attribue. Better way is to find birthday field and then go top.

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='birthday']/.." position="after">
    <group string="New group">
        <group>
            <field name="new1" />
        </group>
    </group>
</xpath>
```

Comment: Actually it is forbidden since Odoo V9 to use `string` in XPath and the non-XPath variant.